# Regular Expression for Windows Restricted Words

Tags: java, regex

How to write a regular expression to capture Windows restricted names such as COM1 or COM2 or upto COM9(COM1 or COM2 or COM3 ....or COM9).

Answer (score 4):

Because Windows filenames are not case sensitive you should don't forget the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("CON|PRN|AUX|NUL|(COM|LPT)[1-9]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

For anyone who's interested - here is the MSDN link to the documentation of the Windows naming conventions: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks dude I got it..This is to identify windows restricted words
 private static final String REGEX_RESTRICT_FOLDER_NAME = "COM[1-9]|LPT[1-9]|CON|PRN|AUX|NUL|CON|PRN";

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer,

```
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("abc");
p.matcher("").matches();
```